# Need help in including lib file in my vc++ project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, static-libraries, biometrics

First of all i am a beginner in visual studio so please forgive and guide me if i m going wrong in some way , i am a java and php programmer so i am not new to programming

i want to develop a application which reads fingerprint , i use this device
http://www.egistec.com/en/sensors/fingerprint-es603wb.aspx
which i think uses Windows Biometric Framework  , so i tried to run the code mentioned in this page
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee207405(v=vs.85).aspx

this is what i did

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Windows.h"
#include "Stdio.h"
#include "Conio.h"
#include "Winbio.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{ HRESULT CaptureSample(); }
```

you can find the function CaptureSample() in the second link provided above.
As you can see in the  they said to link Winbio.lib, i know that its a dll in system32 , i did some research and created a Winbio.def file and Winbio.lib file,

**Now my problem is i dont know how to link the lib file** , i added "Winbio.lib" in properties >>LInker >> Additional Dependencies

it shows me the following error
*error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinBioOpenSession@28* 
infact this error appears even if i remove it from Additional Dependencies

please tell me where i am going wrong , should i place the lib file in any specific directory ? should i copy the dll somewhere ? or something else ?

Answer (score 2):

Linker > General > Additional library Directoreis

put the path to the lib

Linker > Input

Put the lib name.

You can find this if you do some googling.

If everything is fine and still does not work, very probable that your lib file is not generated correctly. You can then try use dynamic loading of your dll file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810279.aspx

First loadLibrary is called to get a handle to your dll, then getProcAddress is called to get the pointer to the function. Cast the pointer into the target function defined in your h file. Then you'll be able to call the function.

Comment: do you get the lib file right? the provider of the dll does not provide you the lib file?

Comment: i am using the dll provided in c:\windows\system32
i managed to create the def file like this
"LIBRARY winbio.dll
EXPORTS
    _BioLogonIdentifiedUser    @1
    WinBioAcquireFocus    @2
    WinBioCancel    @3 ............."

and created lib file with visual studio tools

Comment: I guess the name of the function is mangled, and you'll need to append the parameter size to your function name, like in your error messsage WinBioOpenSession@28 ,this should be the function name in your def file, @28 means the parameters of the function is of size 28 in byte.

Comment: And the @1 @2 in your def file should be the same as the ordinal in the dll if the dll does not export function names but only ordinals. But never mind, this will only cause erro during execution rather than compilation.

Comment: Actually, you can dump you lib file with dumpbin /headers xxx.lib. You will see the symbols in the lib file, it should be the same as _WinBioOpenSession@28 including the underscore prepended and the @28 appended. I think when you create from def, underscore will be automatically added, but@28 will not. Please dump your lib to make sure underscore is there, if not then modify your def file to include the underscore.

Comment: i dumped the lib file and saved it as a text file , here is it http://demo.nscript.net/export.txt

Comment: as you said @28 is not appended , should i do something for that ? but the "_" are there, and also the other thing i noticed is , its mentioned "Machine : 14C (x86)", but i am using 64bit os , would that be a problem ?

Comment: Because the default of a VS project is 32 bit, 32 bit has no problem to run on a 64 bit os, unless your dll is 64 bit.

Comment: I see, so you need to add the @28 symbols to the end of the function name. The number is determined from the parameter size of the function, say if the function is like WinBioOpenSession(int,int), then the size is 4+4=8. WinBioOpenSession@8. You don't need to add the underscore since the Visual studio tool is already doing that for you.

Comment: After you get the new def with @28 and the new lib, dump again, and the symbols should be the same as the compiler requires.

Comment: i created a new def file with @28 now when i compile it says "The procedure entry point WinBioCaptureSample@28 could not be located in the dynamic link library winbio.dll", any idea ?

Comment: I checked the winbio dll, it is because the symbol in the dll is not mangled, you need EXPORTS WinBioOpenSession=WinBioOpenSession@28 in def.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Following steps helped me on VS 2015 Community Edition

1. Right click on the project > Properties.
2. Linker > Input > then in the Addition Dependencies put winbio.lib; to front